# How to solve the problem of being prompted for copyright restrictions (not copyright strikes) when I post a video on YouTube?

Tags: youtube, google-play-console, copyright-display

I recently posted a video to youtube that used a "CC BY 3.0 DEED" license for background music, which required me to attach relevant information below the video, which I did as it described. Of course it means that I can use it legally, and after testing, there is no problem.

However, on my YouTube video management page, the video was prompted to be restricted by copyright. For further details, the prompt was: Copyrighted content was found in my video (that is, the background music I declared to use). The impact on the video result is shown as "no impact".
And the status overview is "The Content ID claim on your video has no impact on your channel. This is not a copyright strike."

I think this is no problem. But when I link this video to Google Play Console as a promotional video for my app store listing, it never displays properly.

My guess is that when Google Play Store displays search results, YouTube video links for product details will not be displayed if there is a copyright notice.

So I wanted to try to get around this "not a copyright strike" prompt.

Has anyone encountered similar problems?

After my test, if the YouTube video has just been released and does not receive a "copyright prompt", searching for my app's product details in the Google Play App Store can link to the YouTube promotional video normally. Therefore, my guess is that the Google Play App Store has stricter restrictions on the product promotion videos displayed.